# Creating an Alert in Sentinel by REST API (Graph) for Azure Sentinel

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-sentinel

I was looking at [Alerts APIs for Microsoft Security Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/alert?view=graph-rest-1.0) and it seems like you can't create a new alert by an API? I was wondering if there is anyway I can programmatically create a new alert into Azure Sentinel?

Answer (score 0):

Security alerts are supplied by Microsoft security providers, so creating alerts is not currently an allowed method under Microsoft Graph Security. However, you can create incidents from alerts in Azure Sentinel. Please refer to [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sentinel/create-incidents-from-alerts).

Answer (score 0):

There is currently a Sentinel REST API that you can programmatically interact with Azure Sentinel, see below (Swagger 2.0 Specs, in preview)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/securityinsights/resource-manager/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/preview/2019-01-01-preview/SecurityInsights.json

For creation/update of a new incident, see example: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/securityinsights/resource-manager/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/preview/2019-01-01-preview/examples/incidents/CreateIncident.json

For a creation of a scheduled alert rule: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/specification/securityinsights/resource-manager/Microsoft.SecurityInsights/preview/2019-01-01-preview/examples/alertRules/CreateScheduledAlertRule.json

Hope this helps, I assume by "alert" you mean an incident.